# What is the hook for the list of products?

Tags: prestashop

I need a hook that I can't find in the documentation, but logically it should exist.
In my module, I need to add some html in category page (or search results page) after the tile with the products but before pagination.

Which hook is best to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default hook for your goal, but you can create your own one and use it within your module. The inconvenience is that you will be able to use it only in modified themes or you will need to add it manually to all new ones. To create the desirable hook you need to put

```
{hook h='displayYourHook' info=$someData}
```

in the top of `your_theme/templates/catalog/_partials/products-top.tpl`
and then just use it like a default hook within your module

```
public function hookDisplayYourHook($params)
{
    // $params can be some information. ID of category for example
    do all necessary stuff here
}
```

and also do not forget to register your hook during the module installation

```
public function install()
{
    ....
    && $this->registerHook('addproduct')
    ....
}
```

Also, I presume that you use prestashop 1.7.* if not - some code can be different